# save properties file android apps

Tags: android, properties

I have a problem to store a properties file in android, this is the code:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.config));

Utils.log(context,"db.version =>"+ prop.get("db.version"));

prop.setProperty("db.version", "2");
String fileName = context.getResources().getString(R.raw.config);
FileOutputStream fos = new  FileOutputStream(fileName);
prop.store(fos, "");
```

when i try to load (and print) there isn't problems, but when i try to save my new set, I receive FileNotFoundException

here LogCat:

```
03-22 18:05:03.262: INFO(11536): db.version =>1
03-22 18:05:03.262: ERROR(11536): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /res/raw/config.properties (No such file or directory)
```

thanks in advance...

Comment: try this `pro.load(YOUR_CLASS_NAME.class.getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));`

Comment: or if u have file in assets folder then `pro.load(YOUR_CLASS_NAME.class.getResourceAsStream("/assets/config.properties"));`

Answer (score 2):

I had already read what azertiti suggest me, but i thought there was a easier way to manage a key-value pair

however, I used SharedPreferences

at first, I created a property xml file in res/xml/conf.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="My preference"
        android:key="preference">

        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="pwd_request"
            android:defaultValue="true"
        />

    </PreferenceCategory>        
</PreferenceScreen>
```

after, I called (in activity class) methods to read/write property value:

```
//read...
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.conf, true);
userProps = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Utils.log(this, userProps.getBoolean("pwd_request", false));
//...and write
edit.putBoolean("pwd_request", false);
edit.commit();
```

in my opinion:
i don't know if what I wrote is the correct way to do that, but I think it isn't a nice Android architecture to manage property fields, it's a merge of java traditional Properties and a method to manage user interface....why do I have to declare my property CheckBoxPreference??..it's just a property.

Comment: The PreferenceScreen you used is designed for displaying an activity with preferences not for storing data. If you want to store some values that have predefined values you can load them first using the method from your original post than save them using SharedPreferences. Another option to provide those default might be to have them as default values in case the property is not defined, like your code for getBoolean. In any of these cases you do not need the PreferenceScreen nor it's a good way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write a file part of the .apk. You can't update anything from your application's apk at runtime.

Reading is fine and that's why you don't have any issue there. If you want to save some preferences might want to check this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref